# Website link shows a code variable

Tags: websites

A website I frequently visit is showing an error message.

The usual Click 'here' link actually shows

> Click '$host_variable.xxxxxxName'

to navigate to a certain page.

Is it a security flaw? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me this seems more like a bug than a security flaw. If the security of the site were breached, I would expect that the text remains the same (cause now it looks suspicious), but only the actual href changing to some malicious host. It could however well be that there is malicious intent involved here, which could best be confirmed by validating the destination of the link.